# Composite pattern and instanceof

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite, instanceof

let's imagine the following situation: I want to design a bidding application (like ebay) with the composite design pattern

I create an abstract superclass like "BidComponent" (which has getName()) and two subclasses "Article" and "Category".

Category has a List which can contain other BidComponents, Article does not implement a List but a getPrice() method.

If I want to iterate through this structure and I want to print out the Category-Article-Structure I need instanceof:

```
if(element instanceof Article){
  Article article = (Article)element;
  System.out.println(article.getName() + ":" + article.getPrice());
}else{
  Category category = (Category)element;
  System.out.println(category.getName());
}
```

This seems pretty wrong to me. Is there a better way to realise this (So without always checking the type via instanceof)? I ask this question because I read several times that using instanceof is bad design...

//Edit to mention my problem with Visitors:

Ok. But let's imagine I want to search the highest bid to all products. So I have

```
public class HighestBidVisitor implements BidComponentVisitor{
    private double highestBid = 0d;

    public HighestBidVisitor(Category category){
        visitCategory(category);
    }

    @Override        
    public void visitCategory(Category category){
        Iterator<BidComponent> elementsIterator = category.iterator();
        while(elementsIterator.hasNext()){
            BidComponent bidComponent = elementsIterator.next();

            //Now I have again the problem: I have to check if a component in the Categorylist is an article or a category
            if(bidComponent instanceof Article) visitArticle((Article)bidComponent);
            else visitCategory((Category)bidComponent);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void visitArticle(Article article){
        if(article.getPrice() > highestBid) highestBid = article.getPrice();
    }


}
```

But now I have the same problem again (See comment in visitCategory). Or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

```
public interface BidComponentVisitor {

  void visitArticle(Article article);

  void visitCategory(Category category);
}
```

Then your `BidComponent` class would have a visit method:

```
public abstract void visitChildren(BidComponentVisitor visitor);
```

The Composite and Visitor patterns often work together.

*Edit:* The key to avoiding `instanceof` when using the vistor pattern is how you implement the `visitChildren` method. In `Category` you would implement it like this:

```
@Override
public void visitChildren(BidComponentVisitor visitor) {
  vistor.visitCategory(this);
  for (BidComponent child : children) {
    child.visitChidren(visitor);
  }
}
```

Since `Article` has no children, it's implementation is simpler:

```
@Override
public void visitChildren(BidComponentVisitor visitor) {
  vistor.visitArticle(this);
}
```

They key is each concrete class in the composite pattern knows it's own type, so it can call the specific visitor method that has a parameter with it's specific type.

One variation is to have enter and exit methods in the visitor for any class with children:

```
public interface BidComponentVisitor {

  void visitArticle(Article article);

  void enterCategory(Category category);

  void exitCategory(Category category);
}
```

With the above interface, `Category.visitChildren()` would look like this:

```
@Override
public void visitChildren(BidComponentVisitor visitor) {
  vistor.enterCategory(this);
  for (BidComponent child : children) {
    child.visitChidren(visitor);
  }
  vistor.exitCategory(this);
}
```

To print the tree, you could do something like this:

```
public class PrintingVisitor implements BidComponentVisitor {
  private int depth = 0;

  private void printIndent() {
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
      System.out.print("  ");
    }
  }

  public void visitArticle(Article article) {
    printIndent();
    System.out.println(article.toString());
  }

  public void enterCategory(Category category);
    printIndent();
    System.out.println(category.toString());
    depth++;
  }

  public void exitCategory(Category category) {
    depth--;
  }
}
```

The disadvantage of the visitor patter is your visitor class needs to either hardcode every possible subclass, or have a generic `visitOther()` method.

Comment: I disagree, this seems too complex to me. Why not just make some getDescription() method that returns a String and override it in both classes with their own implementation?

Comment: @ABoschman if all you need is `getDescription()` then your solution would work (feel free to add it as an answer) but if you need anything more complicated it won't help. Visitor helps make your design open for extension but closed for modification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my first post which explains the problem with your solution... May you can help me solving this?

Comment: To give a specific example, if you want the user of your API to change the way it displays the Category-Article structure, an API where you return a String description would be inflexible. You could extract a `Description` object, but then the caller couldn't take advantage of new properties of the children (including traversing grandchildren).

Comment: @Sotnem curious why you accepted the other answer. Your question only mentioned the visitor pattern after I suggested using the visitor pattern, and I think I answered your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the visitor implementation wrong.  The different Components handle their own dispatching of elements.  They know what type they are so you don't need to do any instanceof checks.

```
public interface Visitor{
   void visit(Article a);

   void visit(Category c);

}

abstract class BidComponent{
   ...
   abstract void accept(Visitor v);
}

public class Category{

  ....
  public void accept(Visitor v){
      v.visit(this); // visit Category
      for(Article a : getArticles()){
         v.visit(a); //visit each article
      }
  }
}
```

Then a visitor to find the highest bid

```
public class HigestBidVisitor implements Visitor{
   private final double highest;

   void visit(Category c){
      //no-op don't care

      //or we could track which Category we have visited last
      //to keep track of highest bid per category etc
   }

   void visit(Article a){
      highest= Math.max(highest, a.getPrice());          
   }
}
```

Then to search all:

```
HigestBidVisitor visitor = new HighestBidVisitor();

BidComponent root = ...

root.accept(visitor); 
double highest = visitor.getHighestPrice();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any clean solution right now. You might have to update your implementation to either store `Article` and `Category` instances separately.

With your current implementation where a `List<BidComponent>` needs to be traversed and each element needs to be processed based on it's type, this approach can be a bit better:

```
abstract class BidComponent {
    public abstract String process();
}

class Category extends BidComponent {
    @Override
    public String process() {
        return getName();
    }
} 

class Article extends BidComponent {
    @Override
    public String process() {
        return getName() + " " + getPrice();
    }
}


List<BidComponent> list = ..;
for (BidComponent c : list) {   
    System.out.println(c.process());
}
```

Another way to decouple the processing logic from the classes/objects is:

```
Map<Class<?>, Function<BidComponent, String>> processors = new HashMap<>();
processors.put(Category.class, Category::getName());
processors.put(Article.class, a -> a.getName() + " " + a.getPrice());

List<BidComponent> list = ..;
for (BidComponent c : list) {
    System.out.println(processors.get(c.getClass()).apply(c));
}
```

Note that this uses Java 8 lambdas but the same can be implemented with Java 7 or lower by using your own interface (similar to [Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)) or the ones provided by [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) or Apache Commons.